# Escaping "this" or @ character in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Accessing a web API I'm getting a JSON response similar to:

`example: { @param: 1 }`

In javascript, I could access this with `example.@param` but in coffeescript, `@` is a reserved word and a shortcut for `this` so it throws an error "Parse error on line #: Unexpected '@'".

How can I access this variable?

Comment: in javascript example.@param doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in coffeescript

```
e={"@param":1}
```

then

```
e["@param"] # get @param value
```

`e={@param:1}` is not valid javascript if @param not surrounded by quotes , it will be a valid json because in json keys must be quoted.

Comment: Good point. That's what I get for making examples up out of thin air.

Answer (score 1):

Use this notation:

```
example['@param']
```